# Conditionally providing enum reflection in CPP

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a structure that takes a non-type parameter (an enum) that can be void in some cases. If the non-type parameter is not void, the structure will need another parameter which of type of the enum.

Currently, it is defined as

```
template<typename U, typename T, T... TArgs> // TArgs was made variadic making this not mandatory
struct {"some variables that depend on the above params" }target_struct;
```

The struct object is created as follows

```
target_structure<double, trial_enum, trial_enum::one_value> obj_1;
target_structure<double, void> obj_2; // To change
```

I want the second declaration to be like:

```
target_structure<double> obj_2;
```

What are the changes necessary for this? Even the variadic parameter is not a neat thing.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `template<typename U, typename T = void, T... TArgs>`?

Comment: `template<typename U, auto... TArgs>` might also be an alternative (changing first sample to `target_structure<double, trial_enum::one_value> obj_1`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jarod42. Your second one was helpful. Your first comment errored out.